# CALayer transform different when animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer, uiviewanimation

This has been driving me crazy. I am using s `CATransform3D` to animate the main layer of my view (to apply a perspective effect). I have a function called `ApplyPerspective` that sets it up, and `ClearPerspective` which resets the layer's transform property to `CATransform3DIdentity`.

Here's my code:

```
    ApplyPerspective(self.mainContentView);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:self.animationDuration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         ClearPerspective(self.mainContentView);
                    }
                     completion:nil];
```

The issue I am having is that the perspective transform applied by `ApplyPerspective` is incorrect. If I remove the -`animateWithDuration` call, but leave the `ApplyPerspective` call, the layer is rendered as expected. I am not sure why the behavior is changing when animated.

I have tried changing the duration, animation curve, flattening the function calls, but I am unable to trace the source of this error.

Update to add bodies of ApplyPerspective() and ClearPerspective():

```
void ApplyPerspective(UIView *aView) {

    // Magic numbers derived using debug sliders
    CGFloat zDist, rotRads, xOffset, yOffset, scale, shift;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        zDist   = 172.5378;
        rotRads = 2.6531;
        xOffset = -13.0;
        yOffset = 402;
        shift   = -241;

    }
    else {
        zDist =     513.4995;
        rotRads =   1.0007;
        xOffset = 0.0;
        yOffset =   -100.0;
        scale = 1.0;
        shift = 0.0;
    }

    CATransform3D p = CATransform3DIdentity;

    p = CATransform3DTranslate(p, xOffset, yOffset, 0.0);

    p.m34 = 1.0 / -zDist;
    p = CATransform3DRotate(p, rotRads, 1.0, 0.0, 0);

    p = CATransform3DTranslate(p, 0, shift, 0.0);

    aView.layer.transform = p;
}

void ClearPerspective(UIView *aView, UIView *parentView) {
    aView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
}
```

Here's the view hierarchy: mainContentView is a child of the ViewController's root view, which uses auto layout. The constraints are such that mainContentView fills the root view. mainContentView has a sibling image view which is used as a background during the animation.

Comment: You need to provide some more code that shows the context of your question. Show us how you setup your perspective, as well as what your ClearPerspective function does.

Comment: Fair enough, I updated to include the function bodies.

Comment: I've been wrestling with this off and on for the past month. I have more clues, but no closer to the solution. The problem is linked to the m34 attribute. If I leave it alone (never forcing it to a value), then the animation starts as expected (of course lacking the desired perspective). The m34 parameter seems to be causing the view to be offset, but I can't figure out why it would be doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it! Apparently some transforms can affect auto layout, and the frame of `mainContentView` was being modified by the layout engine, even though the transform was being reset to the identity transform.

The fix is to send `-layoutIfNeeded` to the parent view (`self.view` in my case) to force layout, and again after the animation is complete. I am posting this since others may run into something similar.

If your transforms aren’t looking right, send `-layoutIfNeeded`.